# game state manager cannot be resolved in my gamestate package

Tags: java, eclipse

Im a 2d java platform developer. I need help with the gamestate manager. Im making a death sequence and would simply like to reroute the game back to the menu upon dying. My code is currently this (do keep In mind I have a gamestate manager aswell as a game state of course, and I use java eclipse.):

```
     public void hit(int damage) {
     if(flinching) return;
     health -= damage;
     if(health < 0) health = 0;
     if(health == 0) dead = true;
     if (dead == true) gsm.setState(GameStateManager.MENUSTATE);
     flinching = true;
     flinchTimer = System.nanoTime();
```

Please help

Comment: In which package is the GameStateManager class defined? Did you import that package?

Comment: for some reason I cant, I cant extend 2  classes.

Comment: It's true that you can't extend two classes. However, I don't see anything in the code you've posted that would hint at why you would need that. You need to *import* the GameStateManager class, and you certainly can import more than one class in a Java file.